On the Connection Between Holy Mass and the Book of Revelation---Looking for Ancient References
For the beginnings of an explanation regarding the correlation between Holy Mass and the Book of Revelation, one may see Scott Hahn's article here: The Apocalyptic Mass.
The same author also has published a book called "The Lamb's Supper (The Mass Explained as Heaven on Earth)." The book is described here: The Lamb's Supper.
The said book is written in a very popular style and it uses a lot of personal pronouns.
I am hoping to obtain, if such exists, a much more rigorous theological treatise on the subject.
QUESTION: Does anyone know of any much older books or theological treatises written perhaps by any of the ancient Fathers or Catholic Saints which have attempted to explain the connection between the Catholic Mass and the biblical Book of Revelation?

For full disclosure, I used bing chat to get this, but I knew there was another book because The Lambs Supper seemed to be the "Popular Science" take on the subject and Dr. Scott Hahn is a pretty smart and rigorous theology professor.
It turns out, he wrote another book called The End: A Study of the Book of Revelation  you can check it out on archive.org

Thank you for providing this link; I hope to peruse some of it a little later.

Also, if you know of any eminent theologians from days gone by (e.g., Suarez, a Lapide, etc.) who may have written, however briefly, on this matter---I would be grateful to learn of it.
